# Display video inside a view which is presented from another controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an application in which i have a collection view. On the click of collection view I am presenting another view controller. This view controller contains a video. When the play button is clicked the video plays but the issue when I click on the full screen button of video it crashes. Anywhere in the app if I add a video and click on full screen to make it full screen it crashes.

This is my code:

```
 - (void) didSelectItemFromCollectionView:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        NSDictionary *cellData = [notification object];
        UINavigationController *navigationcontroller;
        if (cellData)
        {
            if (!self.detailViewController)
            {

                self.detailViewController = [[CourseDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CourseDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

            }
            self.detailViewController.detailItem = cellData;

            [self presentViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

this is the code to present the video view controller from the collection view cell.
Inside the coursedetailcontroller.

in the viewDidLoad

```
  -(void)viewDidload
    {
      MPMoviePlayerController *mc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:nil];

        mc.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        mc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

        NSURL *contentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"01 01. Welcome" withExtension:@"mov"];
        mc.contentURL = contentURL;
        mc.view.frame = self.test.bounds;
        //test is the view where i am displaying the video

        mc.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [mc prepareToPlay];
        [self.test addSubview:mc.view];

        self.testvideo = mc;


    }
```

All works fine but when the video is entered in full screen mode the app crashes.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView trackRectForBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa45f180' this error message is shown
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs when it crashes?

Comment: @EricGenet *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView trackRectForBounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa45f180' this error message is shown

Comment: Hi Rani. If someone improves the case, spelling or spacing errors in your post(s), or trims chatty material, please liaise with them instead of rolling it back. If you cannot come to an agreement with them, one party will need to involve a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

Using MPMovieViewController creates a lot of problem in my opinion. You can try `AVPlayerViewController` to play your video.

You can add this as a subview to your view like this:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"videourl.mp4"];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

self.avPlayerViewController=[[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
self.avPlayerViewController.player=self.avPlayer;    
[self addChildViewController:self.avPlayerViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
```